# Reverse proxy to an authentication server and webserver

Tags: apache, http, authentication, reverse-proxy, varnish

For a while my team and I have been working on an API server with a client. We would like to use a separate server as authentication server. Consider the diagram below.

```
+----------+
|          |
|  Client  |
|          |
+-^------+-+
  |      |
 (6)    (1)
  |      |
  |      |
+-+------v-+            +----------+
|          +----(2)----->          |
|  Proxy   |            |   Auth   |
|          <----(3)-----+          |
+-^------+-+            +----------+
  |      |
 (5)    (4)
  |      |
  |      |
+-+------v-+
|          |
|  Apache  |
|          |
+----------+
```

Right now we have Varnish Cache set up as this reverse proxy, it works fine up to one very important problem. To realize the flow above we have to restart the varnish loop after the authentication server has been polled for validity of some provided access token *in the headers* by the client. The quirk here is that when sending a POST request (that also needs to be authenticated) varnish will omit the POST request body after the restart loop. The API will never receive any POST data (https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/652). This is where we're stuck.

The main question is: how do we realize the flow that we're trying to accomplish in the diagram? Ideally we keep using varnish as reverse proxy *and* caching mechanism, but I don't have any issues if we need to setup a different reverse proxy and let Varnish just be a caching server in between the proxy and the API. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: We're currently considering building a custom solution ourselves using Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, Varnish has (currently) close to no handling of request or response bodies.
However, it it pretty good with headers.

Can you change the application so there is enough information to do the authentication by the headers alone?

POST to an URL with auth tokens embedded in them, or add additional request headers. (X-auth-token: foo)

I'd also recommend using the [CURL VMOD](https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-curl) to call out to the authentication server instead of using restarts. Makes the VCL much more readable and easy to debug.

Comment: the cURL vmod was mentioned by someone else as well. Also I don't think you quite understood what I meant. The problem is that a POST request is meant for the API to begin with. The access token is already in the headers. The proxy checks a remote auth server for the token in the header and based on that either forwards or bounces the original POST request.